# mysqli_connect difference to mysql_connect

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I need to convert php 5 code to php7.
All mysql statements are converted using a script that defines such functions:

```
function mysql_connect($host, $username, $password){
    global $dbconnect;
    $dbconnect = mysqli_connect($host, $username, $password);
    return $dbconnect;
}
```

The nice thing is - it works on php7.

Now I rewrote all scripts using mysqli_connect instead.
However then the first function using mysqli fails.

```
mysqli_connect(): (HY000/1044): Access denied for user
```

If I switch back to `mysql_connect` it works and fails again at the next mysqli command.

Why?

EDIT:
full code of the connect:

```
function db_connect() 
{
    global $db_sql_hostname,$db_sql_database,$db_sql_user,$db_sql_password;
    require_once 'db-config.php';
    global $db_handle;    
    $db_handle = mysqli_connect($db_sql_hostname, $db_sql_user, $db_sql_password, $db_sql_database) or die("Konnte nicht zum mySQL-Server verbinden: ".mysqli_error());
    mysqli_select_($db_sql_database, $db_handle) or die("Konnte die Datenbank ".$db_sql_database." nicht oeffnen: ".mysqli_error());    
    return $db_handle;
}
```

Note that everything works with mysql_ commands. The variables are correct!

EDIT2: this is db-config.php

```
<?php
  $db_sql_hostname   = "hostIP";
  $db_sql_database   = "dbname";
  $db_sql_dbuser     = "dbuser";
  $db_sql_dbpassword = "dbpassowrd";
?>
```

Comment: What is the full error message? You can obscure the user/host if you want.

Comment: Did you specify a database to connect to? I've had it as the fourth parameter in mysqli_connect call.

Comment: Your code calling `mysqli_connect` probably does not pass the correct parameters...

Comment: @RudyM: not specifying a database would not result in _Access denied for user_ error...

Comment: @JiriHrazdil , even so, I'd specify the db. Access denied if you're logging in as a user that only has access to a specific db in the server.

Comment: With `mysqli_connect()`, you cannot specify a port in the host-parameter - as you can in `mysql_connect()`. Perhaps that's it? If you need to specify a port, it's the 5th parameter in `mysqli_connect()`.

Comment: I added the full code. The parameters are correct!

Comment: PHP version is 7.0.20

Comment: Can you show how you define those variables? You should however mask them, just how you define and the structure of them, like `$db_sql_hostname = 'host:port` or something.

Comment: That being said though, just defining your own `mysql_*` functions that subsequently use `mysqli_*` functions isn't the greatest idea if it's a permanent thing. When using `mysqli_`, you should utilize prepared statements, and that requires you do rebuild almost every query.

Comment: @RudyM: you are not correct. Even when a user does have access only to a specific database and you connect without specifying the database name, no error is raised. Only when you try to perform a query, you may get an error message `SELECT command denied to user '...'@'...' for table '...'`

Comment: Maybe see how this wheel rolls, before you try re-inventing it: https://github.com/dshafik/php7-mysql-shim

Comment: I'd like to second what Qiriel here is saying. Jamming in a shim layer like this is a last-ditch option. You have an opportunity now to audit all your SQL calls and correct any that don't encode things properly. Using prepared statements with placeholder values can dramatically improve your site's security and can eliminate entire classes of bugs that you might never have fixed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing `TRUE` as database name (fourth parameter of `mysqli_connect`), which results in error:

_Warning: mysqli_connect(): (HY000/1044): Access denied for user '...'@'...' to database '1' in...

Change the line to:

```
$db_handle = mysqli_connect($db_sql_hostname, $db_sql_dbuser, $db_sql_dbpassword) or die("Konnte nicht zum mySQL-Server verbinden: ".mysqli_error());
```

Comment: Now the error changes to the next line `mysqli_select_db() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli`

Comment: You did not mention `mysqli_select_db()` in the code you posted here, so some more code from your side would be required. But do you pass `$db_handle` to `mysqli_select_db()`?

Comment: I added the full function. I do pass the handle.

Comment: I found the origin of my problems. mysqli_ commands require the connection variable always first. Whereas this is not the case with mysql_ commands. So I had to change every line using a mysql command. It now almost works (Still some lines wrong).

Answer (score 0):

mysqli_connect requires the parameters
`mysqli_connect(ip,user,password,database)`

where as 
mysql_connect requires
`mysql_connect(ip,user,password)`

Thus specifying the correct database and removing true will solve you problems

Source: PHP documentation

http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysqli-connect.php

http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php

Comment: I posted the suggested code. I however does not work. The error is `Warning:  mysqli_select_db() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, string given in ...`

Answer (score 0):

in you function

```
function db_connect() 
{
    global $db_sql_hostname,$db_sql_database,$db_sql_user,$db_sql_password;
    require_once 'db-config.php';
    global $db_handle;    
    $db_handle = mysqli_connect($db_sql_hostname, $db_sql_user, $db_sql_password, $db_sql_database) or die("Konnte nicht zum mySQL-Server verbinden: ".mysqli_error());
    mysqli_select_($db_sql_database, $db_handle) or die("Konnte die Datenbank ".$db_sql_database." nicht oeffnen: ".mysqli_error());    
    return $db_handle;
}
```

`mysqli_select_()` should be `mysqli_select_db()`
and specify `$db_handle` as first parameter then the name of the the database ie.
`myslqi_select_db($db_handle,$db_sql_database)`

Look at this documentation for more clarity.
http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.select-db.php